# Extra paramater(s) in setTimeout: earliest IE version support?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, version, settimeout, setinterval

To avoid implied eval and unnecessary code I would like to use:
`setTimeout(alert, 1000, "Hello");`

instead of:
`setTimeout('alert("Hello")', 1000);`
or:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("Hello");
},
1000);
```

Now I have read that IE supports this from IE8 and up, if I run it from the emulator (in IE11) though, it seems that even IE9 doesn't support it.

Can anyone tell me if this is true for the actual versions of IE8 and IE9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fails for me in both IE9 and IE8: http://jsbin.com/nuranote/1 Works for me in IE10 and IE11.

Interestingly, [they don't mention this support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the IE Dev Center page for `setTimeout`...

Now, if `alert` was just an example but you're not going to be doing this with host-provided functions (which aren't always backed by `Function.prototype`), you can do this:

```
// Won't work with `alert` on IE9 but does with real JavaScript functions.
// Even `alert` works IE10+ (they finally got it about Function.prototype)
setTimeout(yourFunction.bind(null, "Hello"), 1000);
```

That still creates a function, but in a (theoretically) slightly more optimized way. (You have to shim that for IE8 and earlier, possibly a couple of other older browsers.)

Comment: But succeeds in 10, just like the emulator?

Comment: @Jonathan: Just finished firing up that VM. Works in IE10. (And IE11)

Comment: Thank you. Since IE9 doesn't support it I won't use it I guess. And yes I thought it was weird too that MSDN specifies the third param as `language`.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yeah. :-) Stick with the version passing in the function. Or use `bind` (just added that).